# AngularJS 1.6 compatibility with default browsers of Kitkat and Marshmallow

Tags: android, angularjs, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-4.4-kitkat

I am not an AngularJS expert. We have  a single page application developed using Angularjs 1.6 and Bootstrap. The rendering is not proper when its opened in default browsers of Android Kitkat or Marshmallow. Looks like AngularJS 1.x doesn't have support for older browsers.

Going through the web, understand recent Angular provides more mobile compatibility and migrating to Angular would fix it. We got to release it for mobile soon and have enough time to do the migration.

Is there anyway by using polyfills or Modernizr to make the same AngularJS 1.6 application working in the older browser or migrating to Angular is the only way  for supporting older default browsers of Android Kitkat or Marshmallow?

[image]

Getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module loginApp due to:
>
> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'loginApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
>
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/nomod?p0=loginApp

Comment: @halfer thanks for checking my question. I have update question with the image. In our index.html we have 3 divs controlled by ng-show. In the old android browsers all ng-show seems to be not working. Also angular translate is not working.

Comment: Getting Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module loginApp due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'loginApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/nomod?p0=loginApp